# What is wrong with my conversion of X Y Z co-ordinates to screen X Y co-ordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on a HTML5 Canvas demo of spheres bouncing in 3D space. This is very simple to do. Each ball has X, Y, and Z co-ordinates. These co-ordinates are then converted into screen X and Y co-ordinates that I read here. http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/496030.html

The formula that I got from the above link to convert X Y Z co-ordinates into X and Y is

```
screenX = (depth/(Z+depth)) * X
screenY = (depth/(Z+depth)) * Y
```

I have put a demonstration of the working code in jsFiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/xeMpv/

But something is off here. [The result I get looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2bOy.png). Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is exactly the problem? they doesn't bounce? or they doesn't move at all?

Comment: They do bounce as intended, but I want it to look like I was looking at the "room" from a center. But it looks like it is skewed to the top left.

Comment: because 1. your coordinate system is relative to the top left, not the center, and 2. all of your positions are in the positive octant - you never pick negative values for x and y.

Answer (score 3):

Currently your origin (origo) is in the top left corner. To project `x` and `y` so that your origin, or here: the Cartesian coordinate `[0, 0, 0]` is in center of the screen:

```
f = fieldOfView / (viewDistance + z);
px = x * f + screenWidth * 0.5;
py = y * f + screenHeight * 0.5;
```

- `fieldOfView` is related to focal distance, use for example 128 - 256.
- `viewDistance` translates `z` values.
- `px` and `py` are the projected 2D coordinates.

If all your coordinates are positive they will be drawn on the right/bottom side of the origin so you need to use negative values to have something on the left/top side of it.

Additionally: you can replace the line operations with `rect()`s and if you cache them to an off-screen canvas you can "blit" that to main canvas instead of clearing and re-drawing each time which gives you a little better performance.