# HTML clear animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

i am trying to clear canvas animation using if statement, but when i click the clear button nothing happens, any suggestions. also do i need ho delete the objects to save memory, or once i clear the canvas it frees memory

```
    <canvas id="demo" width=720 height=550></canvas>
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
```

.

```
var doChange = true;
window.onload=function(){

var demo= document.getElementById('demo');
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
doChange=false;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);
console.log("clear");
}, false);

var animObjects = [];

animObjects.push(new animRectangle(ctx, 0, 90, 80,80, 'yellow', 3, 3));



 loop(doChange);


function loop(doChange) {

if(doChange==true){

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);

    for(var i = 0, ao; ao = animObjects[i]; i++) {
        ao.update();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

}

function animRectangle(ctx, x, y, XSize,YSize, color, dx, dy) {

var me = this;

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.XSize = XSize;
this.XSize = XSize;
this.color = color;
this.dx = dx;
this.dy = dy;

var bool = 0;

this.update = function() {

    if (me.x < 0 || me.x > ctx.canvas.width-80){
        me.dx = -me.dx;
    }
    if (me.y < 50 || me.y > 200){
        me.dy = -me.dy;
    }
    me.x += me.dx;
    me.y += me.dy;

    render();
}

function render() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(me.x, me.y, me.XSize, me.XSize);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = me.color;
    ctx.fill();
}
return this;
}
```

Comment: i have made some changes to the code, but it still doesn't work, now it just clears the objects but there is no animation i think something is wrong with the if statemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the global `doChange` with a local variant in your function. As rAF is passing in it's time used it will always be "true" (`> 0`) and as you don't do an explicit test (`==` versus `===`) a non-zeroe value will always go as "true".

I would also recommend you to do all operations (in this case) in the conditional checks and not segment them as your code is asynchronous.

For example, modify this snippet to just set the flag:

```
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
    doChange = false; /// set global flag to false
}, false);
```

Then in the loop do the conditional checks and move the operation inside:

```
function loop() { // can't pass arguments in here as rAF will pass in used time
                  // and it will override the global doChange

    if (doChange === true) { /// explicitly check for boolean using ===

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);

        for(var i = 0, ao; ao = animObjects[i]; i++) {
            ao.update();
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);

    }
}
```

Note that the way your condition works here the loop will end when check is clicked. If you want the loop to continue to run you must move rAF out of the condition check block.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation, i was trying to do this for a while, also do i need to delete the objects(animObjects) to free up memory

Comment: @KarishKarish no problem. We as programmers have no way to control memory GC in JavaScript. You can try to unreference all instances but it will be up to the browser to clear unused objects (or not).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "demo" variable is not defined, you want to use "canvas" variable instead. Try this (changed 'demo' to 'canvas', lines 3 and 4 in your second code snippet):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('demo');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: Thank you i have made some changes to the code, but it still doesn't work, now it just clears the objects but there is no animation i think something is wrong with the if statement

Comment: You are welcome. I can't see where you actually looping your animation, maybe it's a built-in function that I just don't notice, I am not sure. Here, however, is a good example on animation with canvas, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223390/canvas-animation-with-clearrectx-y-w-h?rq=1

Comment: This does not matter. All elements with an id can be referenced directly. Best practice can be discussed of course, but the only result with this code is that OP is using two references to the same element - both will work, but isn't optimal.